# Exit a child process after forking

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork, pid

I have this code and it's goal is to create N child processes and print out each PID and process number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void childProcess(int num)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    printf("Hello! I am process no. %d! my PID is %d!\n", num, pid);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        childProcess(i);
        _exit(3);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

However after trying multiple ways: e.g `exit` vs `_exi`t, recursion in `childProcess`, `pid = wait()`, I am still having trouble creating only 5 processes. With this code so far my output is:

```
Hello! I am process no. 1! my PID is 96196!
Hello! I am process no. 1! my PID is 0!
```

I'm not sure how to properly exit from a child process. Without the exit the code creates N! processes.

Comment: When you say you are trying to create 'N child processes', what is 'N'? Is it the iterator value in the for loop?

Answer (score 11):

You are correctly exiting child process, it is just that you do it at wrong time. After fork() every child process keeps running same loop as parent, creating another child processes and that's why you end up having a lot of them.

Correct code would be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (fork() == 0) {
    // child process
    printf("I'm child %d, my pid is %d\n", i, getpid());
    exit(0);
  }
  // parent process keeps running the loop
}
```

Comment: Actually, he has just one of them then he calls `_exit(3)` from both, the child and the parent...

Comment: Does exit(0) achieves parallel processing nevertheless i.e. 5 Childs running independently and exiting at their own time?

Comment: @FahadNaeem no. Each process only executes the first loop iteration and hits _exit(3). This includes the main process. So only two processes are ever running.
The main process starts one child, printfs and exits. Child process printfs and exits. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` splits your process into two processes, a parent and a child. You need some sort of test of its return value inside `childProcess()` to figure out if you're in the parent or the child. If `pid` is 0 then you're in the child; if non-zero then you're in the parent. Based on that you'll want to *conditionally* exit the program.

Comment: That's interesting, so then if you don't mind me asking, whenever I changed my childProcess to include an if statement to only operate when pid != 0 the pid that is being printed is incremented by 1.

Why is that if that is the parent?

Comment: What is the return value of `fork()`? Check the documentation. It's not the current process's PID.