# TCP protocol - multiple clients connecting to the server using fork()

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp

I created client and server modules which I can summon through main.

I don't know why when I launch the server and start a client it's ending with message:

> Launched server
>
> Waiting for clients to connect...
>
> Connection accepted from: 127.0.0.1:35346
>
> Number of connected clients: 1
>
> Received 22 bytes from the client: Hello from the client!
>
> Sending a response message...
>
> Unable to accept!

And the prompt character shows up.

What's even weirder: when I don't do anything with the server terminal and start another client it's showing message:

> Connection accepted from: 127.0.0.1:46398
>
> Number of connected clients: 2
>
> Received 22 bytes from the client: Hello from the client!
>
> Sending a response message...
>
> Unable to accept!

And again character prompt. Why there is such a strange behavior?

This is server.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

void server()
{
    const int PORT = 8888;
    
    std::cout << "Launched server" << std::endl;

    pid_t childPid;
    int socket_fd;

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create a socket!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to bind a socket!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(socket_fd, 5) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to listen\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in cliAddress;
    int cliAddress_size = sizeof(cliAddress);
    int client_fd;
    int cnt = 0;

    std::cout << "Waiting for clients to connect...\n";
    while(1)
    {
        if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&cliAddress, (socklen_t*)&cliAddress_size)) == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to accept!\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        std::cout << "Connection accepted from: " << inet_ntoa(cliAddress.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(cliAddress.sin_port) << '\n';

        std::cout << "Number of connected clients: " << ++cnt << "\n";

        if ((childPid == fork()) == 0)
        {
            close(socket_fd);

            char buffer[1024] = {};
            int bytes_received = read(client_fd, buffer, 1024);
            std::cout << "Received " << bytes_received << " bytes from the client: " << buffer << "\n";

            auto msg = "Hello from the server!";
            std::cout << "Sending a response message..." << std::endl;
            send(client_fd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
        }
    }

    close(client_fd);
}
```

And this is client.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

void client()
{
    const int PORT = 8888;

    std::cout << "Launched client" << std::endl;

    int client_fd;

    if ((client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create a socket!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in cliAddress;
    cliAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    cliAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    cliAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    std::cout << "Waiting for clients to connect...\n";

    int server_fd;
    if ((connect(client_fd, (sockaddr*)&cliAddress, sizeof(cliAddress))) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to connect!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    auto msg = "Hello from the client!";
    send(client_fd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

    char buffer[1024] = {};
    int bytes_received = read(client_fd, buffer, 1024);
    std::cout << "Received " << bytes_received << " bytes from the server: " << buffer << "\n";
}
```

This is main.cpp:

```
#include "server.hpp"
#include "client.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Specify the mode: server OR client" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "server") == 0)
    {
        server();
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "client") == 0)
    {
        client();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's compiled with Makefile:

```
output: main.o
    g++ -std=c++20 main.o -o output

main.o: main.cpp client.hpp server.hpp
    g++ -std=c++20 -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o output
```

And then: ./output server and ./output client in separate terminals.

Comment: Your child process closes `socket_fd` and then wants to accept when it loops.

Comment: Unfortunately when I erased close(socket_fd) from the child process parentheses ++cnt doesn't work the way it supposed to work: it sometimes increases and sometimes not when calling another instance of client. Also ""Waiting for clients to connect...\n""  sometimes appears in pairs.

Comment: Are you expecting the child process to exit after sending the response?

Answer (score 1):

I took reference from the below stackoverflow links:

[Exit a child process after forking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596984/exit-a-child-process-after-forking)

[Multiclient server using fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669474/multiclient-server-using-fork)

The main differences I made to the server code are:

1. Close the client socket fd once it is used for sending the message to the client.
2. Exit the child process after socket send is completed. In the main process, indicate that it is ignoring the child process's exit status using

   ```
   signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
   ```
3. Added additional if, else if cases for calling fork() system call.

Please find the modified server code below.

```
#pragma once
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

void server()
{
    const int PORT = 8888;
    
    std::cout << "Launched server" << std::endl;

    pid_t childPid;
    int socket_fd;

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create a socket!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to bind a socket!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(socket_fd, 5) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to listen\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

    struct sockaddr_in cliAddress;
    int cliAddress_size = sizeof(cliAddress);
    int client_fd;

    std::cout << "Waiting for clients to connect...\n";
    int cnt = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&cliAddress, (socklen_t*)&cliAddress_size)) == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to accept!\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        std::cout << "Connection accepted from: " << inet_ntoa(cliAddress.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(cliAddress.sin_port) << '\n';

        if ((childPid = fork()) == -1) {
            close(client_fd);
            continue;
        }else if(childPid > 0) {
            close(client_fd);
            ++cnt;
            continue;
        }
        else if(childPid == 0) 
        {
            std::cout << "Number of connected clients: " << ++cnt << "\n";
            char buffer[1024] = {};
            int bytes_received = read(client_fd, buffer, 1024);
            std::cout << "Received " << bytes_received << " bytes from the client: " << buffer << "\n";

            auto msg = "Hello from the server!";
            std::cout << "Sending a response message..." << std::endl;
            send(client_fd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
            close(client_fd);
            _exit(3);
        }
    }
}
```